# how to define this dictionary in silverlight XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I want to Define Dictionry with the following XAML

```
Dictionary<Tuple<ModifierKeys, Key>, ICommand>
```

I know I need to create class that inherit IDitionary , byt how to call it or use it withtin the XAML

on the level of the usercontrol , I want to creat shortcutlist , to pass to global behavior that catch keydown in MVVM model , so I want to pass this dictionary to the Behavior to check against

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to achieve? This will help you get better answers. It may well be that there is a better way of doing it, but without the context no one will be able to suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your xaml supports it (I'm no expert on Silverlight) you can use x:TypeArguments in your xaml.

See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476(v=vs.100).aspx for more information.

If your xaml do not support it, a very simple way to achieve this is to create your own class that will inherit the dictionnary with the type parameters you want :

```
public class YourTuple
{
    public ModifierKeys ModifierKey { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}

public class YourClass : Dictionary<YourTuple, ICommand>
```

and then use it directly in your xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SO.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:SO="clr-namespace:SO"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SO:YourClass>
            <YourCommand ...>
                <YourCommand.Key>
                    <YourTuple ModifierKey="..." Key="..."
                </YourCommand.Key>
            </YourCommand>
            ...
        </SO:YourClass>

    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```